# Alignment in VLD1

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

I have a question about ARM Neon VLD1 instruction's alignment. How does the alignment in the following code work?

```
DATA            .req r0  
vld1.16         {d16, d17, d18, d19}, [DATA, :128]!
```

Does the starting address of this read instruction shifts to DATA + a positive integer, such that it is the smallest multiple of 16(16 bytes = 128 bits) which is no less than DATA, or DATA itself changes to the smallest multiple of 16 no less than DATA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a hint to the CPU. Only thing I read about the usefulness of such hint was from a [blog post](http://blogs.arm.com/software-enablement/161-coding-for-neon-part-1-load-and-stores/) on ARM's site claiming it makes the loading faster, it doesn't say how or why however. Probably because CPU can issue wider loads.

> > You can also specify an alignment for the pointer passed in Rn, using the optional : parameter, which often speeds up memory accesses.

If you provide the *hint* you must make sure that `DATA` is aligned to 16 bytes otherwise you'll get an hardware exception.

This hardware behavior is described in VLD1 description in [ARM ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0406b/index.html) as

```
if ConditionPassed() then
    EncodingSpecificOperations(); CheckAdvSIMDEnabled(); NullCheckIfThumbEE(n);
    address = R[n]; if (address MOD alignment) != 0 then GenerateAlignmentException();
    if wback then R[n] = R[n] + (if register_index then R[m] else ebytes);
    Elem[D[d],index,esize] = MemU[address,ebytes];
```

mainly this line

```
if (address MOD alignment) != 0 then GenerateAlignmentException();
```

I actually can't understand why CPU can check alignment itself and apply the best condition. May be that would cost too much cycles.

Comment: I see. The alignment requires the address register to be multiples of alignment if alignment is used. It will fail otherwise.

Comment: It's not exactly a HINT; it's functional, and neccessary if you want optimum performance. According to ARM 8A docs, with alignment unspecified, VLD1Q makes 4 data bus accesses to load. With :64 alignment, VLD1Q  takes two bus accesses. VLD1Q with :128 takes 1 bus access. Without an alignment specifier, the instruction can load data from any alignment; with an alignment specifier, the CPU generates an exception if the data is not correctly aligned. So a fairly major performance difference if you don't specify the alignment.